# Display Lists in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, optimization

I heard that there was a faster method of displaying vertices, rather than recreating the GL_TRIANGLES, each time the scene is drawn. I thought I read somewhere that this method was  obselete. Why would the OpenGL group remove something that was faster? Even if it is obselete, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Check out OpenGL VBOs too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue is that OpenGL 3 deprecates immediate mode rendering, which means you can't use `glVertexXX` etc to draw your triangles. If you aren't using immediate-mode rendering, display lists don't help you get any additional performance.

What you should be using are Vertex Buffer Objects (supported since version 1.5). As with display lists, VBOs allow you not to re-send the entire scene to the GPU every frame, resulting in a huge performance boost.