# 3D space game development

Tags: 3d, mmo

I want to develop a 3D game (sci-fi type with spaceships) which can be played on multiplayer mode and by multiplayer i mean around 10 players for start as it will be a personal testing project and mostly educational. I have been searching for some days about the available languages and engines but i am kinda confused. Since i have been learning Java for my 1st year in I.T university and i have pretty good understanding i thought i would go with the Java language and develop that game on an applet so it could be played on a browser. After going through an applet game tutorial i understood how graphics work on an applet.

So.. 1st question: Could an applet carry the burden of a 3D game especially on multiplayer? My thinking: It's a space game so the graphics should not be such a big problem since it wont be that crowded with entities apart from ships, planets and some effects.

If the java applet is not the way for my project i would't mind "developing it on desktop"(i mean not making it a browser game). 2nd question: Should i use Unity engine for my purpose(space game)? If not name other language/engine combo.

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask here. It sounds to me like you need to slow down and learn a bit more first. Diving into a 3D multiplayer game is a pretty big undertaking for someone who has only just started development of any kind.

Comment: I apologize if the question is off topic, i was redirected from stackoverflow. When you say "learn a bit more first" you mean practicing on 2D single-player games?

Comment: Please check out the question "[Is Java viable for serious game development?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25492/is-java-viable-for-serious-game-development)", and also notice the links under "Related" on the right hand side of this page. Also feel free to join us in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19), where you are welcome to start discussions like this one. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, Java can carry the burden of a 3D game:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuneScape

Java is not the only language you can use for a browser game. You mentioned Unity too, but there's also Flash (Actionscript) that now supports hardware rendering with stage3D, and has a nice library Away3D. You won't code your server in Actionscript or Unity, though.

I'd suggest learning one thing at a time:

- a complex 2D game, where you will learn the language, and MVC
- modifying a ready game to have multiplayer functionality, where you will learn server language, as well as many connection issues like client-server desynchronization
- Adding another dimension to the game.
- Adding MMO functionality, logging in, storing data in database, making sever scalable and secure.

I'll add next point in 10 years, when you finish those :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i can finally move on :)